# Page not rerendering after history.push()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router with my React dictionary project, and for some reason my page doesn't re-render after I run `history.push()` (using the `useHistory` hook from react-router). I have a search bar, and I use this function to go to a new link.

```
const KeyPressHandler: KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.currentTarget;
    if ((event.code === "Enter" || event.code === "NumpadEnter") && value.length)
      history.push(`/dictionary/${value}`);
    };
  };
```

My `App` component looks like this:

```
const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  ...
  return (
    ...
      <Route path="/dictionary" component={DictionaryEntryPage} />
    ...
  );
};
```

This is what the `DictionaryEntryPage` component is:

```
const DictionaryEntryPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [wordData, setWordData] = useState<WordData[] | undefined | null>(undefined);
  // useRouteMatch is imported from react-router
  const match = useRouteMatch<{ requestedWord: string }>("/dictionary/:requestedWord");

  useEffect(() => {
    const { requestedWord } = match?.params ?? {};

    if (requestedWord) {
      (async () => {
        const data = await parseWordData(requestedWord);
        setWordData(data || null);
      })();
    } else setWordData(null);
  }, []);
  
  const wordDataEls = wordData ? wordData.map((data, i) => <Word {...data} key={i} />) : <Loading />;

  ...
}
```

Let me know what I should add to/remove from the question, and [here](https://dictionary-app-wi4oqeexl-theayokhan.vercel.app/)'s a demo link if someone want to see it.

Comment: Can you post full code for your app component?

Comment: or a link to your repo if it's on GitHub. I suspect you are missing dependencies in your useEffect, there, in `DictionaryEntryPage`. I believe you _probably_ need `match` in there as a dependency to force that effect to re-run when the match changes. But I really would like to look at the repo to be sure. If you try that and it resolves it, I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining why

Comment: log your `match` or `requestedWord` and check if it is `null` or `{}`

Comment: Nevermind, I went and found the repo and confirmed that your issue is missing dependencies in your useEffect. I will put together an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll actually find that your component is re-rendering properly. The issue is with your `useEffect`, rather than an issue with rendering.

In your `useEffect`, you have an empty dependencies array at the end `[]`. By having an empty dependencies array, you are essentially telling React that nothing will *ever change and cause this side effect to re run* (which is not the case). If that is truly your desire, and you only want the side effect to run when the component first mounts, you should remove the dependencies array altogether, which would cause your code to look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { requestedWord } = match?.params ?? {};
    console.log('ran effect');
    if (requestedWord) {
      (async () => {
        const data = await parseWordData(requestedWord);
        setWordData(data || null);
      })();
    } else setWordData(null);
  });
```

What you *really* want, though, is to actually cause that effect to re-run every time the search term changes. Leaving everything else about your `useEffect` the same, that'd give you this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const { requestedWord } = match?.params ?? {};
    console.log('ran effect');
    if (requestedWord) {
      (async () => {
        const data = await parseWordData(requestedWord);
        setWordData(data || null);
      })();
    } else setWordData(null);
  }, [
      match
  ]);
```

The above still has some problems, though. Namely, `match` is an object, which means it's a reference type. When deciding whether or not to re-run a side effect, React only does *shallow* comparisons rather than deeply inspecting reference types to see if they are equal (check out [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/value-vs-reference-javascript/) for a better explanation of reference vs value types). Basically, if you leave the `useEffect` like that, you'll be running the effect *too* much and probably get yourself lots of rate limit errors from your API.

So, the *final* example of what you want is this:

```
const DictionaryEntryPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [wordData, setWordData] = useState<WordData[] | undefined | null>(undefined);
  const match = useRouteMatch<{ requestedWord: string }>("/dictionary/:requestedWord");
  const { requestedWord } = match?.params ?? {};

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('ran effect');
    if (requestedWord) {
      (async () => {
        const data = await parseWordData(requestedWord);
        setWordData(data || null);
      })();
    } else setWordData(null);
  }, [
    requestedWord
  ]);

  //...
}
```

Now you're extracting the `requestedWord` (which is a string and therefore a value type) at render and your `useEffect` simply has a dependency on that string. Now your effect will be making the correct number of requests to the API *and* it won't have stale data about the requested word.

As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend that you install the [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) and add it to your .eslintrc.json and extend from it. It has a rule called `exhaustive-deps` which would have caught this and warned you ahead of time.

Additional reading about exhaustive dependencies: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: Thank you very much! I was quite confused on what was wrong, and this cleared it up for me. I'll make sure to add the `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` package to my project.